# Reading string timestamp in UTC as UTC time using DateTime class joda time library

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have a timestamp in string, which is in UTC timezone, i want to read it as is in UTC timezone using DateTime in joda time library.

Example:

```
String utcTs = "2016-06-01T14:46:22.001Z";
```

when i try below stmt., DateTime is reading it and converting to servertimezone where ever the application is running!!

```
DateTime dtUtcTs = new DateTime(utcTs);
```

Is there a way i can force the DateTime to read the string timestamp as UTC ?

My application server is in CST, and when print the date with SOP stmt like below, i am observing CST time instead of UTC!!

`System.out.println(dtUtcTs)` ==> gives me date in server where the application is running!!

Thanks a lot!!

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class TestClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

String utcTs = "2016-06-01T14:46:22.001Z";
DateTime dtUtcTs = new DateTime(utcTs);

System.out.println(dtUtcTs)

}
}
```

below is the output i see, my application server is **in CST** zone

```
2016-06-01T09:46:22.001-05:00
```

using **joda time version 2.9.1**

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime%28java.lang.Object,%20org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29

Comment: @4castle a DateTime **does** have a timezone. The joda equivalent of a java util Date is an Instant.

Comment: Are you sure your text actually has a `Z` on the end? I'd expect that to be fine, and it works on my machine.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes there is `Z`

Comment: And how are you determining that it's converting it to the server time zone? Please provide a [mcve] so we can reproduce.

Comment: @JonSkeet edited my question with details.

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce that on my machine. It works fine. Again, please show a [mcve] showing *exactly* what you see, and please specify the version of Joda time, too.

Comment: @JonSkeet s.o.pln(variable) is giving me value in server timezone

Comment: That's not what I asked for. Just provide a short but complete program - mine is 9 lines long - and include the output. Don't *describe* the output - include it verbatim. Edit that into your question, along with the version of Joda Time.

Comment: Joda Time is obsolete - use the `java.time` package, you can easily convert into any timezone or parse as UTC with that : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: @JonSkeet edited question with more details.

Comment: Thank you - although the code you've posted wouldn't compile, and you *still* didn't include the version of Joda Time you're using (now fixed). (When people are trying to help you, *please* try your best to comply with their requests.) I've worked out why I couldn't reproduce it before - and the answer is reasonably simple Will post in a minute.

Comment: lol ... `new DateTime(utcTs, DateTimeZone.UTC)`. You're welcome. And now please do a beginners' tutorial on programming.

Comment: @JonSkeet included joda time version. Sure, i am including details as requested. :)

Comment: @Raja note that the first comment you got was a direct link to the documentation of the constructor to use. You didn't read the javadoc, and you apparently didn't even click the link either. Sigh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the overload of the `DateTime` constructor that takes a `DateTimeZone`:

```
DateTime dtUtcTs = new DateTime(utcTs, DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Another option is to use a `DateTimeFormatter` so you can specify *exactly* the format you expect, and what time zone you want.

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "2016-06-01T14:46:22.001Z";
        DateTime dt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()
            .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
            .parseDateTime(text);
        System.out.println(dt);
    }
}
```